# getAuth() returns null

Tags: firebase-authentication

I need to use the user authentication for facebook,twitter and google. I initially created a firebase account and used this following code.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://keks.firebaseio.com");
    ref.getAuth();
    console.log(ref.getAuth());
```

This always returns null in my console. Why this happens? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `getAuth()` doesn't authenticate the user, it only returns the current authentication state. The [API documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/getauth.html) says:

> Returns the current authentication state of the Firebase client. If the client is unauthenticated, this method will return `null`.

Since you are getting `null`, it means your user hasn't been authenticated yet. You can authenticate the user, by calling `authWithOAuthPopup()`:

```
function authHandler(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
}
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("<provider>", authHandler);
```

This last snippet comes from the [Firebase documentation on authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-login).

Since both parts of my answer come from the Firebase documentation, I highly recommend that you spend some time there.

Comment: does authData comes from authWithOAuthPopup() ?@Frank van Puffelen

Comment: It is passed into the callback by `authWithOAuthPopup()`.